# Extract boundary from merged polygon QGIS

Tags: polygon, line, boundaries

Summary of situation: i got several layers with different parts of one territory, there are not only boundaries and square but also other stuff (i mean all lines inside) [image]

I merged layers and turned polygons into lines. But i need to get just boundaries of general territory without "insides" and i don't know how to do it.
[image]

I tried to use dissolve tool, bot the result isn't correct. I had to use the "remove hole" function and merge the parts that are left, but it didn't work :(
[image]

Help me please

Comment: Please ask questions in English on this site. From what google translate says you've combined layers but how did you do this? There are many ways to combine layers. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here; what do you say are *insides*? If you have converted the polygons to lines as a shapefile there is no way they can be filled.

Comment: Hello, Michael
Summary of situation: i got several layers with different parts of one territory, there are not only boundaries and square but also other stuff (i mean all lines inside). A need to get just boundaries of general territory without "insides" and i don't know how to do it.
What have i done: layers merging and polygons into lines turning
I use QGIS 3.28.3

Comment: I think you want to dissolve by a single attribute, have a read of https://gisrsstudy.com/qgis-dissolve/ and see if that is something like what you want to achieve.